# What is the correct way to use a package on different environment?

Tags: node.js, module, package, require

I have 3 different environment : development, staging and production

In each of those environnement, I have a nodeJS application that uses a package that I created.
The package is hosted in a private npm registry that I self-host.

I'd like the development application to use to development version of my package, the staging application to use the staging version of my package, and so on ...

At first I wanted to create 3 version of my package (`my-package_development`, `my-package_staging`, etc) but it was not maintainable

**What is the correct way to do that ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of below approach

---

### Approach 1

Use environment variable inside your package:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
        case "development":
          //enter code here
          break;
        case "staging":
          //enter code here
          break;
        default:
          //enter code here
}
```

run your code like this

```
NODE_ENV=development node server.js
```

---

### Approach 2

Pass the environment directly to your package

```
const package_name = require("your_package")(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

and then use the switch case to execute the code accordingly

```
switch (env){
            case "development":
              //enter code here
              break;
            case "staging":
              //enter code here
              break;
            default:
              //enter code here
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not looking to have a different behaviour according to the DEPLOY_ENV variable, I'm looking for a way to use my "production version" of my package with my production app.

I can't use the approach you describe since it would forced me to have the 3 different version of my package in a single version of this package